# How To Access and Click Button PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, wordpress, phantomjs

I am trying to automatically download a plugin on my wordpress site by implementing phantomJs. For some reason, I cannot seem access the download button (shown below)
[image]

This is the HTML code to the image (with domain sensitive information blurred out for security purposes)

[image] 
So far, I have tried accessing this element by using the following code:

```
function() {  
page.evaluate(function() {
  let mainLink = document.querySelector('a[data-slug="better-wp-security"]')
  mainLink.click()
    })
 }
```

Some things to mention:

- This function, as it is part of a larger file, will NOT execute until the page has finished loading.
- PhantomJS is executing correctly, there are no problems with permissions
- The script before-hand is properly accessing the install plugins page, which I verified by capturing screenshots before trying to click.
- I have defined `click` earlier int he file, it works perfectly.

Any ideas how I can accomplish this? Thanks all!

**ADDED INFORMATION:**
It seems as if the path from the main `div` element is as follows:

```
#the-list .plugin-card plugin-card-better-wp-security .plugin-card-top .action-links .plugin-action-buttons .install-now button
```

I imagine the solution to this question has something to do with this sequence.

Comment: I'm not sure at the end, what's wrong?

Comment: @Vaviloff For some reason PhantomJS cannot find the element with the specified data slug. All I am trying to do is find the button so I can click it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by now going after the `data-slug` attribute, but rather going after the `href` element itself. Although I can't generate my own `wponce` value without the use of the Rest API, I was able to search the document to find an `href` that contained certain parts of the url. This is the final code below:

```
document.querySelector('a[href*="action=install-plugin&plugin=better-wp-security"]').click()
```

That's it! Simple and easy!